# Menu mobile, altura de despliegue

Tags: wordpress, programación-móvil, menu

Tengo problemas con el menu mobile de mi sitio wordpress con el menu mobile, al hacer click no llega al encabezado de la seccion, sino mas abajo. No logro dar con la seccion para editar la altura de despliegue en mobile. Ojala puedan ayudarme, gracias.

Comment: A ciegas es muy difícil, somos programadores, no adivinos. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Hace falta que agregues un [mre] de ser posible. Saludos

Comment: Bienvenido, agrega más información a tu pregunta, revisa [ask]